# Time and Space Complexity of 2 Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

```
def bar(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n+bar(n-1)
def foo(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return bar(n)+foo(n-1)
```

Hi, I have just learnt about space and time complexity. Can anyone confirm with me whether I'm right to say the time complexity of `foo` is O(n**2) and the space complexity of `foo` is O(n)? Not too sure about the time complexity as `foo` calls `bar` which only calls itself once, while `foo` always calls out 2 functions.

Comment: Hint: You're always calling the `bar` from 1 to n, for 1 to n in `foo` function.

Answer (score 0):

Each time that you're calling the `foo` with lets say `T` as the input argument, you're calling `bar` from `1` to `T - 1`. That means you're doing something like following:

```
foo's input     bar's inputs  
   1                1,
   2                2, 1,
   3                3, 2, 1
   4                4, 3, 2, 1
  ...
   n                n, n-1, n-2, ...
```

Therefore, number of calls are as follows:

```
1,   2   ,   3    ,     4      , ...        t

1 ,(1+2) , (1+2+3) , (1+2+3+4) , ... (t+t-1+t-2+...+1)
```

This is a recursion equation and you can just put the recursion equation of `bar` in place of `n` and simply find the big `O`.

This means that the complexity of `foo` is O(t<sup>2</sup>) and since the complexity of `bar` is `O(n)` by placing `n` in `foo`'s equation you will get O(n<sup>2</sup>).

You can also check this very simply by adding a `print('*')` before the `return` line in `bar` to check the number of calls:

```
In [42]: foo(2)
*
*
*
Out[42]: 4

In [43]: foo(3)
*
*
*
*
*
*
Out[43]: 10

In [44]: foo(4)
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
Out[44]: 20
```

As you can see for 2 we have 3 calls for 3 we have 6 calls and for 4 we have 10.

Comment: If you have a sum of O(n) terms each of which is a sum from 1 to n, that suggests the overall complexity is O(n^3).

Comment: @rwp The OP is learning the concepts I'm not trying to give him/her the answer.

Comment: Sorry for letting the cat out of the bag.

Comment: @Kasramvd
Hi, may I ask what kind of assumption have I made by calculating big O like this that doesnt coincide with this context?

        T(n)=time complexity of foo
        A(n)=time complexity of bar

        T(n)=A(n)+T(n-1)
        =A(n)+A(n-1)+T(n-2)
        =A(n)+A(n-1)...A(n-(k-1))+T(n-k)
        =k*O(n)+T(n-k)   [Since A(n)=O(n)]
        =nO(n)+T(0) [n=k]
        =O(n**2)

Your logic seems to make alot of sense, but mine seems so too. Trying to find an explanation for the difference.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth Just because you see the `+` between `bar` and `foo(n-1)` in `bar(n)+foo(n-1)` doesn't mean the overall complexity has a linear relation to them as well. This is to say that the conclusion `T(n)=A(n)+T(n-1)` is wrong or not necessarily true.

Comment: @Kasramvd Do you mind giving me an example of a piece of code(with the similar context of bar and foo), 
where I can safely assume that the conclusion T(n)=A(n)+T(n-1) is True?

If possible, please include the first line of how to approach the problem from a similar fashion like T(n)= <some expression of n>, then I can figure out the math from there. The resources provided to me do not cover alot about the n**2 and n**3 cases. Thanks for the help earlier and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth It's not possible to explain all of these here in comments. I'd strongly recommend you to ask your question in https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kasramvd Alright, thanks for the redirect. Actually after looking at your solution closely, I don't think I agree with your solution 1+(1+2)+(1+2+3) as u seem to be assuming each call of foo will call that number of times of bar indirectly,eg n=3 is 3rd bracket, 6 times of foo, but no matter how I count it, it shouldnt be the case as foo calls bar, but bar doesnt call foo. Your solution should be fully agreeable if there is true mutual recursion(both calling each other) and not just one sided. So I would think 1+2+3+4...=O(n**2) would be more accurate. Please give feedback thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The space complexity here is actually the maximum depth of the call stack during the program execution and it's `O(n)`. For time complexity of `foo` you can count the number of function calls:

```
NC(foo(n)) = NC(bar(n)) + NC(foo(n-1)) + 1
```

Since it's obvious that `NC(bar(n)) = n + 1`, we have (ignoring those constant "+ 1" parts):

```
NC(foo(n)) = n + NC(foo(n-1)) = n + (n-1) + NC(foo(n-2)) = 
= n + (n-1) + ... + 1 = n(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)
```